# Show agents and Replicator task be both run at the same time?

Tags: ibm-domino

We are running a scheduled agent which updates every single document in a very large database. Is it a good idea to keep replicator running whilst every single document is updated via the scheduled agent?

Any tips or advice would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well: when replicator runs, it takes a kind of "snapshot" of things to do and works on them. That said, it will not be a problem, to run both tasks simultaneously, but might cause some disk io peaks.

I would recommend to schedule replication after the agent run, to not have to much performance impact on the server.

And I would check,if it really is necessary to change ALL documents in that database on every agent run, as usually this is just because of some lazyness of programmers and not very often really is necessary...

Comment: Thanks Torsten for your response. This was a one time agent in a large database with 1.5 million documents where the change affected all documents (data cleansing). I was advised that small bursts of replication might be better than trying to sync 1.5 million documents all at one time, but was not really sure if this would affect the agent at all.